# Xamarin, effect of platform build tools (android)

Tags: xamarin.android, android-build

I'm coding on xamarin to create an Android-form test application in vs2017. 
The coding isn't the problem its rather the environment.
So far the biggest problem has been getting it all to work in vs2017.  I managed to get it mostly working, with minor (yellow) errors left.

Now the device xaml preview works !!
The Visual studio / (or should I say intel Haxm) emulator works !!
And I can use the live player as well !!.
My program can be seen on all of above (also on my mobile).

So now that it finally all works (fixing the environment took quite a while).
I got carefully to update my environment and xamrin, and I wonder I have installed Android build tools 26 and 25. (As I want my code to run on my older 4.4.2 version of android phone. Would it be fine to install android build tools 27.0.3 as well??.

Or will adding another sdk-build-tools cause havoc (dependency troubles).
I'm not sure if those build tools are independent from the rest of xamarin / .net core

Comment: Thanks new to android, you could type your comment as solution and i'll reward it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build tools used, should be latest only,sdk build tools are independent, if u r talking about sdk tools then u can add as many as u want like if u want your emulator to be run on that sdk version then u need to download or else downloading multiple sdks will affects only to size nothing else